# errors in my commands on easyphp devserver

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, easyphp, easyphp-devserver

i wish to run the following command on my easyphp devserver from the server thats running on my machine but there are so many errors that i dont know the meaning of.

i went from an old version of easy php(old version that school uses) to the recent build.

```
CREATE DATABASE UserCredentialsADVHproject IF NOT EXISTS UserCredentialsADVHproject;
USE UserCredentialsADVHproject;
CREATE TABLE Credentials(
    Username varchar(16) NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY CHECK (LEN(Username)<=16),
    Password varchar(16) NOT NULL CHECK (LEN(Password)<=16));


INSERT INTO Credentials (Username, Password)
VALUES ("User", "Password");

CREATE DATABASE ExercisesADVHproject IF NOT EXISTS ExercisesADVHproject;
USE ExercisesADVHproject;
CREATE TABLE Exercises(
    Name varchar(25) NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    Position varchar(8) NOT NULL CHECK(Type IN(“Seated”, ”Standing”, “Lying”, “Kneeling”)),
    Equipment varchar(9) NOT NULL CHECK(Equipment IN("Dumbbell", "Barbell", "Bodyweight", "Machine", "Cable")),
    bodyPart varchar(5) NOT NULL CHECK(bodyPart IN(“Legs”, ”Back”, “Chest”, “Arms”, “Core”))
    beginnerStandard int NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK(beginnerStandard<100),
    noviceStandard int NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK(noviceStandard<150),
    intermediateStandard int NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK(intermediateStandard<200),
    advancedStandard int NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK(advancedStandard<250),
    eliteStandard int NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK(eliteStandard<500)
    );


INSERT INTO Exercises (Name, Position, Equipment, bodyPart, beginnerStandard, noviceStandard, intermediateStandard, advancedStandard, eliteStandard)
VALUES("Squat", "Standing", "Barbell", "Legs", 64, 93, 130, 173, 219),
      ("Hamstring Curls", "Seated", "Machine", "Legs", 29, 50, 79, 114, 154),
      ("Leg Extension", "Seated", "Machine", "Legs", 35, 61, 96, 139, 186),
      ("Hip Abduction", "Seated", "Machine", "Legs", 30, 59, 101, 153, 213),
      ("Hip Adduction", "Seated", "Machine", "Legs", 32, 64, 109, 167, 233),
      ("Smith-Machine Calf Raises", "Standing", "Machine", "Legs", 31, 72, 134, 214, 304),
      ("Hip thrusts", "Seated", "Barbell", "Legs", 38, 76, 129, 196, 273),
      ("Incline Chest Press", "Lying", "Dumbbell", "Chest", 19, 28, 39, 53, 68),
      ("Chest Fly", "Standing", "Cable", "Chest", 5, 18, 39, 68, 103),
      ("Lat Pulldown", "Seated", "Machine", "Back", 38, 58, 82, 110, 141),
      ("Face Pulls", "Standing", "Cable", "Back", 12, 26, 46, 71, 101),
      ("Bent-Over Rows", "Standing", "Barbell", "Back", 14, 60, 85, 115, 147),
      ("Preacher Curls", "Standing", "Barbell", "Arms", 17, 29, 46, 66, 89),
      ("Lateral Raises", "Standing", "Dumbbell", "Arms", 4, 8, 15, 25, 36),
      ("Tricep Pushdowns", "Standing", "Cable", "Arms", 17, 34, 57, 86, 119),
      ("Incline Bicep Hammer Curl", "Seated", "Dumbbell", "Arms", 5, 11, 21, 35, 50),
      ("Shoulder Press", "Seated", "Dumbbell", "Arms", 13, 21, 32, 45, 60),
      ("Overhead Tricep Extension", "Standing", "Cable", "Arms", 10, 23, 42, 67, 97),
      ("Reverse (Zottoman) Curls", "Standing",  "Dumbbell", "Arms", 3, 9, 21, 36, 55),
      ("Crunch", "Seated", "Machine", "Core", 26, 51, 85, 128, 177),
      ("Torso Rotations", "Kneeling", "Machine", "Core", 21, 41, 62, 82, 103));

CREATE DATABASE TipADVHproject IF NOT EXISTS TipADVHproject;
USE TipADVHproject;
CREATE TABLE Tips(
    tipId int NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    tipName varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    tipDesc varchar(255) NOT NULL);
```

[[image: image of code above in easyphp terminal]]

the following images are the error prompts:
[image]
[errors on ln4 to do with check statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yL3Z.png)
[error on ln4 to do with password column name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cQQw.png)
ln11 has same issue as ln1
[error on ln15 with check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDE8c.png)
line 49 also has same issue and ln 1 and ln11

I tried searching up and looking at syntax of the errors but nothing really helped.
i retyped the whole thing instead of copying and pasting it from a txt file. nothing changed

i appreciate all the help and feedback and if any addition info is needed pls ask

Comment: please share more details, like the error messages you are facing **in text form**, along with your attempts to resolve them

Comment: i corrected some errors https://dbfiddle.uk/Hv3Gdg2Z but you can't check the length of a string, besides it is not necessary as you **should** has it anyway and you need 20my bytes to have it fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you creating a database per table?

Your syntax for `IF NOT EXISTS` is incorrect:

```
CREATE DATABASE UserCredentialsADVHproject IF NOT EXISTS UserCredentialsADVHproject;
```

should be:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS UserCredentialsADVHproject;
```

There's no `LEN()` function and you should get a 1406 error if the data you are inserting is too long:

```
CREATE TABLE Credentials(
    Username varchar(16) NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY CHECK (LEN(Username)<=16),
    Password varchar(16) NOT NULL CHECK (LEN(Password)<=16));
```

should be:

```
CREATE TABLE Credentials(
    Username varchar(16) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Password varchar(16) NOT NULL
);
```

The use of `IN()` to check specific values in your `VARCHAR` is causing an error due to the quoting `“”`:

```
Position varchar(8) NOT NULL CHECK(Type IN(“Seated”, ”Standing”, “Lying”, “Kneeling”)),
```

should be:

```
Position varchar(8) NOT NULL CHECK(Position IN('Seated', 'Standing', 'Lying', 'Kneeling')),
```

or maybe switch to an ENUM which will provide the constraint on values and use less space:

```
Position ENUM('Seated', 'Standing', 'Lying', 'Kneeling') NOT NULL,
```

Comment: originally i was going to add more tables to the seperate databases thats why theres multiple but I'll now consolodate them into one db.

now ive got two errors on the check statements: Username varchar(16) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CHECK (LENGTH(Username)>=8),

i made an error, the data should be greater than 8 characters instead of the >=16
the errors are:
a comma or closing bracket expected near the check
unrecognised statement near Length

I appreciate the help :)

Comment: im not sure if this works: https://dbfiddle.uk/dQids5ql
im using easyphp devserver/phpMyAdmin4.7.0

Comment: i dont know the difference or what one im using
im running my code on a easyPHP devserver on the phpMyAdmin 4.7.0

it says MySQL administration

Comment: i honestly dk. I removed the unique checks from them but when i run on ht eserver it still compains about ln13

Comment: its fine i restarted the server and ran the code again and it worked. i appreciate your help alot :)
have a good day